# Invoked method jakarta.servlet.ServletResponse.getOutputStream() is no accessor method

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlets

Since updating to Spring Boot 3 I get this exception when I try to retrieve ServletOutPutStream from HttpServletResponse. This was never an issue with Spring Boot 2x.

```
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import net.infraview.uss.videoeventapi.entrypoints.UseCaseFactory;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/download")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class DownloadController{

    private final UseCaseFactory useCaseFactory;

    @GetMapping(path = "/{fileName}")
    public void download(@PathVariable String fileName, @RequestParam String ip, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException {

        var output = response.getOutputStream();
        useCaseFactory.makeDownloadVideo(ip, fileName, output)
            .execute();
    }
```

Full exception

```
{
    "type": "about:blank",
    "title": "Bad Request",
    "status": 400,
    "detail": "Invoked method public abstract jakarta.servlet.ServletOutputStream jakarta.servlet.ServletResponse.getOutputStream() throws java.io.IOException is no accessor method",
    "instance": "/download/reports.mp4"
}
```

Has anyone experienced similar issue? If so what was the solution?

I tried the newest Spring Boot 3.1.0 and Spring Cloud Version 2022.0.2
but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution with modification :

FROM ->

```
@GetMapping(path = "/{fileName}")
public void download(@PathVariable String fileName, @RequestParam String ip, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {    
    var output = response.getOutputStream();
    useCaseFactory.makeDownloadVideo(ip, fileName, output).execute();
}
```

TO ->

```
@GetMapping(path = "/{fileName}")
public void download(@PathVariable String fileName, @RequestParam String ip, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    ServletOutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
    useCaseFactory.makeDownloadVideo(ip, fileName, output).execute();
}
```